# Folium : type object 'Map' has no attribute 'FeatureGroup'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, folium

Getting

```
Output as error : AttributeError: type object 'Map' has no attribute 'FeatureGroup'
```

When I run this

```
can_map = folium.Map(location=[56.130, -106.35],zoom_start=4,tiles='Stamen Toner')

ontario = folium.Map.FeatureGroup()

ontario.add_child(folium.features.CircleMarker([51.25, -85.32],radius=5,color='red', fill_color='Red'))

can_map.add_child(ontario)

folium.marker([51.25, -85,32],popup='Ontario').add_to(can_map)
can_map
```

Answer (score 0):

FeatureGroup is not an attribute of Map.  Should be `folium.FeatureGroup(...)`

I made some other fixes that are noted in the comments

```
can_map = folium.Map(location=[56.130, -106.35],zoom_start=4,tiles='Stamen Toner')

# changed folium.Map.FeatureGroup() to folium.FeatureGroup()
ontario = folium.FeatureGroup()

# changed folium.features.CircleMarker to folium.CircleMarker
ontario.add_child(folium.CircleMarker([51.25, -85.32],radius=5,color='red', fill_color='Red'))

can_map.add_child(ontario)

# changed folium.marker to folium.Marker
# changed -85,32 to 85.32
folium.Marker([51.25, -85.32],popup='Ontario').add_to(can_map)
can_map
```